# SQL - How to check if data exists on all available dates?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I'm kind of new to SQL. Is there a possible way to check if the username is exists on a certain range of time.

Let's say there are **4 username** and **time range (date)** between 1 April to 3 April 2021 from **TableExample**. How to check what username are existing on the every available date time?

| username | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uname1 | 1 | 2021-04-01 |
| uname2 | 2 | 2021-04-01 |
| uname3 | 2 | 2021-04-01 |
| uname4 | 1 | 2021-04-01 |
| uname1 | 2 | 2021-04-02 |
| uname3 | 2 | 2021-04-02 |
| uname4 | 2 | 2021-04-02 |
| uname1 | 1 | 2021-04-03 |
| uname2 | 2 | 2021-04-03 |
| uname4 | 2 | 2021-04-03 |

Expected output will be **uname1** and **uname4**

| username | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uname1 | 1 | 2021-04-01 |
| uname4 | 1 | 2021-04-01 |
| uname1 | 2 | 2021-04-02 |
| uname4 | 2 | 2021-04-02 |
| uname1 | 1 | 2021-04-03 |
| uname4 | 2 | 2021-04-03 |

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? It seems to me that it would be possible with `WHERE date BETWEEN ... AND ... GROUP BY username, date HAVING COUNT(date) = 3` but just braistorming - testing is needed

Comment: Do you need distinct uname or distinct dates? if not then simple query as suggested by urban can do your job.

Comment: hi @urban & @swapnil bandiwadekar thanks for the answers! what i've been trying to do is something like this 
`select distinct
 username,
 case when date between '2021-04-01' and '2021-04-03' then 1 else 0 end as username_is_exist
from SQLTutorial..testrun1
where username is not null
group by username, date` but the output still shows every uname "1" instead of uname1 & uname4 "1" then uname2, 3, 5, and 6 "0"

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select username
from t
where date >= '2021-04-01' and date < '2021-04-04'
group by username
having count(*) = 3;   -- user name appears on all three days
```

Note that this returns the username.  If you actually want the details rows, use this in a query using a `join` or similar construct to get the original rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username, type, date
FROM yourtable
WHERE date >= '2021-04-01' and date <= '2021-04-03'
```

Would give you all rows for the specific timeframe.

Should you be looking for an aggregated list of users you want to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username
FROM yourtable
WHERE date >= '2021-04-01' and date <= '2021-04-03'
```

If you want to check for a specific username you can add username = xxx to the WHERE statement. If you want to receive a list of who is listed and who is not you can create a nested select / join statement that then shows you who is and who is not in the data at the given time.

Answer (score 0):

Table with exact your data:

[image: Table with exact your data]

Add one column called `RN(Row_Number)` order by `Date`.

[image: Added one column called RN]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCdJJ.png

Make sure you must take **RN** column only. Below is the fully dynamic query for the future:

```
Declare @d date, @un varchar(20) , @t int,
        @min int = 1 ,  @max int = (Select max(RN) from TableExample),
        @count int = 0
Create table #UN(username varchar(20),type int, Dates date)
Select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Date) SrNo , Date  into #Dates from ( 
Select distinct Date  from TableExample
) as A 
Declare @m int =1 , @mx int=(Select max(SrNo) from #Dates), @dd date
while(@min <= @max)
Begin
    Select @d = date, @un = username, @t = type from TableExample where RN = @min
    
    while(@m <= @mx)
    Begin
        Select @dd = date from #Dates where SrNo= @m;

        if exists(Select Date from TableExample where Date = @dd and username = @un)
        Begin
            set @count = @count + 1
        End

        set @m = @m + 1;

        if(@count = @mx)
        Begin
            insert into #UN values(@un,@t,@d)
        End
    End

    set @m = 1 ;
    set @count = 0;
    set @min = @min + 1
End

Select * from #UN;

Drop table #UN;
Drop table #Dates;
```

Just RUN the above code as it is. You will get the exact answer that you mentioned in your question. Refer image below.

[image: Exact answer]